# Empty string supplied as input in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php on line 327

Tags: magento2.4.3

Keep getting this error in exception, no solutions to find on the internet:

main.CRITICAL: Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/astout/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php on line 327 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/astout/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php on line 327 at /home/astout/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

This happened since monday, when I updated magento -> 2.4.3

As far as I can remember didn't created or changed any .xml file myself

So how to know which xml file it is

Thank You
Alain

Answer (score 1):

There is an empty .xml file in your project and if you don't know where empty file is and you are using Linux, use this command to get a list of empty files.

open terminal and type (Where ***/path/to/dest*** is your actual path like, **/var/www/html/magento2**)

find

> find /path/to/dest -type d -empty

for dir.

and

find

> find /path/to/dest -type f -empty

for file.

Comment: Thank you so much, rather is says the following: bash: /path/to/dest: No such file or directory